# Format time from local time by jquery

Tags: jquery

I have converted UTC time to local time by this snippet:

```
var dateLocal = new Date(startDate).toString();
```

and this's my result: Wed Apr 24 2013 10:42:45 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time) 
I want to format my result to: MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: You should do it either by hand or I propose using [`date.js`](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: I don't want to use another scrip, just jQuery

Comment: Ok, do it by hand then. I mean there is no special features in `jQuery` for handling "datetimes".

Comment: jQuery Is a JavaScript library that abstracts DOM manipulation. jQuery does not include much built-in functionality for manipulating objects outside of that scope, including dates. You'll either have to use the native JavaScript date methods or include a separate Date library.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with pure javascript. I dont thing jquery could help here.

```
var dateString = (dateLocal.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateLocal.getDate() + "/" + dateLocal.getFullYear()+" "+dateLocal.getHours() + ":" + dateLocal.getMinutes() + ":" + dateLocal.getSeconds() ;
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kENgx/)

also there appears to be a [jquery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) for formating date strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the date.js and then try with the following code

```
Date.parse(startDate).toString('MM/dd/yyyy H:i:s')
```